# Bluetooth data transfer iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I want to send 20-30 mb data over bluetooth for iOS.I have looked at Game Kit and other samples such as Send Farts - http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/ , and BeamIt - http://arctouch.com/beamit/ .They all seem to have very low speeds, about 2mb per minute. Could anyone give me a faster solution ?

Comment: bluetooth is not known for speed, 3mb per minute is actually pretty good for bluetooth. You other option would be to use WiFi, either in an adhoc setup or just over the network. But Apple has limited, what we as a developer, to controle of the wifi settings.

Comment: @rckoenes Have a look at this [link](http://vimeo.com/47536324). The speed seems really good here. Bump is an option, so is wifi. But I am looking for bluetooth

Comment: @Gautum-Jain That does look faster, maybe both device have bluetooth 4 which has fast file transfer support. Do you test devices have bluetooth 4?

Comment: @rckoenes Yes, I have tried on bluetooth 4 devices. iPad 3 and iPod 5th generation. 2mb per minute. I wonder how that guy is achieving such speed. I think he has written his own protocol. Any idea how difficult that will be ?